# Azure: The source logical sector size is 4096 and the target size is 512 error during restore

Tags: azure, backup, restore, disk, azure-backup-vault

I have a VM with 4 disks in Azure. I need to restore a backup of one of the disks to recover some files.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D44kK.jpg)

There are two ways to do this that I already tried. (see screenshot)

Method 1: Mount the backup of this disk as a separate disk and manually restore the files.
Problem: When I mount the backup as separate disks, I see all the disks except the one I need. I already tried different backups but the disk I need doesn't appear.

Method 2: I can restore only the disk I need as a new disk in Azure by using Recovery point collection, but I get an error that the sector size does not match the current one (4096 instead of 512) (see screenshot).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib41B.jpg)

Problem: I can't adjust this even if I take the same disk configuration, so Premium SSD v2. The option to change the sector size is greyed out. I tried all of the disks without success.

Can someone please help me out? It can't be that difficult to just restore a backup..